# how do i make my ball bounce off the paddle - processing 4.2

Tags: processing, collision-detection

i've been trying to get my ball to bounce off a paddle (rectangle) which has a fixed y position but an x position controlled by the mouseX but it just wont work, i'm not sure what um doing wrong because i've tried about everything i think makes sense but it just never does what looks right to me.

I've tried thus code and the ball just goes straight through.

```
// Check collision with the rectangle and change velocity accordingly
  if ((x + ballSize/2 >= rectX  && x + ballSize/2 <= rectX + rectWidth) &&( y+ballSize/2 >= rectY  && y+ballSize/2 <= rectY + rectHeight/2)) {
    vx = -vx;
    vy = -vy;
  }
```

I've also tried this and it also goes straight through as well

```
if (x + ballSize/2 >= rectX && x + ballSize/2 <= rectX + rectWidth) {
    if(y - ballSize/2 >= rectY && y - ballSize/2 <= rectY ) {
      vx = -vx;
      vy = -vy;
      }
    }
```

heres the entirety of my code for reference

```
int x = 100;
int y = 100;
float vx = 3.0;
float vy = 2.5;
float rectX = mouseX;
float rectY = 400;
int ballSize = 30;
int rectWidth = 80;
int rectHeight =25;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  
  rect(constrain(mouseX, 0, width-rectWidth), rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight);
  fill(200);
  ellipse(x, y, ballSize, ballSize);
  x += vx;
  y += vy;

  // Preventing ball from going off the sides of the window
  if (x >= width - 15 || x <= 15) {
    vx = -vx;
  }

  if (y >= height - 15 || y <= 15) {
    vy = -vy;
  }

  // Check collision with the rectangle and change velocity accordingly

  
  if (x + ballSize/2 >= rectX && x + ballSize/2 <= rectX + rectWidth) {
    if(y - ballSize/2 >= rectY && y - ballSize/2 <= rectY ) {
      vx = -vx;
      vy = -vy;
      }
    }
    
  }//draw closing bracket
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely here:

```
if(y - ballSize/2 >= rectY && y - ballSize/2 <= rectY )
```

you wanted:

```
if(y + ballSize/2 >= rectY && y + ballSize/2 <= rectY + rectHeight )
```

Anyway, it will bounce only when the center of the ball touches the pad. In case you want more precise collision, you have to have more complicated math here:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/96337/collision-between-aabb-and-circle